# viewpager keeps current fragment between recreating - how to display always first fragment after app killed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I use ViewPager (v4). I noticed that the app keeps the information about the currently selected fragment even if my app is killed (ex. with task killer). Thus ex. after rerunning app I'm returning not to the first fragment but to the one selected before app killing.

How to display always the first fragment when the app is recreated (after being killed)? I though about onCreate method of my activity but this method can be also executed in different moments thus it's probably not the best idea to display the first fragment here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Comment: but in what moment I have to set this? onCreate doesn't seem to be the best idea even if one of the possible ones....

Comment: Moreover when i put setCurrentItem in onCreate it seems to be ignored (I added toast to know when some part of the code is executed).

Comment: It must be the last line in 'onCreate()' or in 'onResume()' otherwise you have to check maybe this line is overriding somewhere by anything else